# Amp no longer valid after creating custom template WordPress AMP

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cpanel, amp-html

Gday

I have created a valid amp page and want to use it for my home page, I tried using WordPress template custom page but it made my page non compliant.

I run off cpanel

So my question is how do I upload the page and use it as my home page without compromising the page.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is currently not AMP compatible without the [amp-wp plugin](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp). However, even with that plugin active, it is impossible to debug this issue without more information regarding your setup, code used, active plugins, et cetera.